# 8.85 x 10^-12 to pow(base, exponent) [Arduino code]

Tags: arduino, pow

I could't find how to change 8.85 x 10^-12 -----> pow(base, exponent)

Here's my code :

```
#include <math.h>  

float Value = 8.85 * pow(10,-12);

void setup()
{

 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()

{

Serial.println(Value);

}
```

My output :

```
0.00
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: how about float Value = 885e-14; ?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Have used  float Value = 885e-14; before

My output :

0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print float value using `%e` format,

```
printf(“Value %e”, Value)
```

`%e` float or double exponential format

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>  

float Value = 8.85 * pow(10,-12);

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
Serial.println(Value,19);
}
```